# asp.net mvc 3 call javascript from controller action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

this is what my controller action looks like -

```
public void GetResizedImage(int height, int width, int GroupingId)
{
    //Generate image here
    image.RenderToStream();
    //here i need to execute "$("#modalDialog").dialog("option", "position", 'center');" to center my dialog after image is rendered.
}
```

In my client side, i am assigning the image src like this -

```
var imgsrc = "Group/GetResizedImage/?height=" + height + "&width=" + width + "&GroupingId=" + GroupingId;
$("#ImageDiv").find("#MyImage").attr("src", imgsrc);
```

And the image is rendered on jquery dialog, so the dialog resizes and it gets hidden in the right side of browser, which creates horizontal scroll bar, and i dont want the scroll bar on my screen

Is there anyway to center my jquery modal dialog after the image is rendered?
I know i used to use `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` in webforms but since this is MVC i cannot use it.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This is not an action method, since its return type is void. A controller action method has to return an ActionResult, or a subclass of ActionResult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to the load event of the image.  Here is some example code since you haven't included all your javascript (I haven't tested this but the load event is the general idea):

```
var imgsrc = "Group/GetResizedImage/?height=" + height + "&width=" + width + "&GroupingId=" + GroupingId;
var img = $("#ImageDiv").find("#MyImage")
img.load(function() {
    // call your resize here
});
img.attr("src", imgsrc);
```

Comment: That is an awesome idea! I wish I could add more than +1

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute script from a controller action method. Controller action methods execute on the server. Javascript & jQuery execute on the browser.

Comment: That is not true. Using page object in asp.net we use to issue JS commands from server. This is correct that in the end JS executed  in browser but we were able to made the execution conditional from server side. To see how to do in asp.net mvc please visit http://mazharkaunain.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-use-aspnet-mvc-javascriptresult.html